# WCF MutualCertificate Not Preserving White Space Issue

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF Service that our customer is trying to consume using a Java client. The signature verification is failing because WCF has PreserveWhiteSpace set to False by default. We can resolve this in code by setting XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace to true, but we're using the MutualCertificate security binding, which verifies the signature internally. The problem is that we can't find a way to set XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace to true in web.config. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you think this is the problem? what error you get in the WCF trace? I do a lot of wcf<-->java interop with mutual certificates and did not see this problem with modern stacks

Comment: The error message that they get with their Java client when trying to consume my service is: “MessageSecurityException: The signature verification failed. Please see inner exception for fault details. ---> CryptographicException: Digest verification failed for Reference...”

Comment: Thanks Yaron for replying. I've seen a lot of your helpful posts on this topic. The problem I have is that I can't set the property XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace to true since the signature verification is happening under the hood (I just use authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" and the .net framework verifies the signuature whithout me having to write code).

Comment: The problem with the black box approach is that I don't have access to what .net is doing (or at least I don't know how to override the functionality). I was hoping to stick with the “out of the box” approach to reduce risk in the long term and the amount of code required.

Comment: They can of course strip the whitespace out of their request, but I have no control over their side (I am the vendor and they are my customer). Note that my service works fine with a .net client, a Java client that I wrote myself to test it, but their client seems to go over a proxy of some sort that inserts the extra white space. I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: do they get a correct response from your service and fail parsing it, or does your service returns an error? Myabe they can do the validation manually on their end. which framework they use?

Comment: The service was generating the error. The have actually made a change on their end to solve the problem. They were inserting white spaces so they just stripped those off. It is working now. Thanks again.